# jquery selector to find a kendo grid column and format

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to apply formatting to a column in my kendo grid on the DataBound Event.   The DataBound event throws a javascript function where i'm trying to select a column and apply some Date formatting.  The bound column looks like this:

```
columns.Bound(c => c.CreatedDate).Title("Submitted on").Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("contains"))).Format("{0: MM/dd/yyyy HH.mm.ss}");
```

The reason i need to do it there is because i have a button that filters the grid,  and upon refreshing the data in the grid it loses the formatting on the date.  The current code i have is:

```
function onDataBound(e) {
        var grid = $("#MyGrid").data("kendoGrid");
        grid.tbody.find('td').each(function () {
            var dataItem = grid.dataItem(this);
            if (dataItem.CreatedDate) {          

                $(this).DoTheFormatting
            }
        });
```

Need help with the jquery selector

Comment: How do you identify the column? Is it moveable or does it remain at the same position (index)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the `e.sender.tbody.children()`, and use the `get` function to retrieve your columns data instead of using magic numbers on column indexes, like so:

```
var rows = e.sender.tbody.children();
for (var j = 0; j < rows.length; j++)
{
    var row = $(rows[j]);
    var dataItem = e.sender.dataItem(row);
    if (dataItem.get("CreatedDate"))
    {
        $(this).DoTheFormatting...
    }
}
```